# Работа с массивом vk API

Tags: php

Есть ответ от vk api, если count стоит больше 1, то код не хочет работать со всем списком, не могу понять, что нужно исправить

```
if ($this->checkbox->selected){
    $offset=200;
    $count=200;
    }else{
    $offset=0;
    }
       $group=$this->edit7->text;
       $token=$this->edit4->text;
       $count=$this->edit9->text;

        $h = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/market.get?owner_id=-$group&offset=$offset&count=$count&access_token=$token&v=5.59");
        $array = json_decode($h,true);

    $this->edit->text=$array['response']['items'][0]['title'];
    $this->textArea->text=$array['response']['items'][0]['description'];
    $this->edit6->text=$array['response']['items'][0]['price']['currency']['name'];
    $this->edit3->text=$array['response']['items'][0]['category']['name'];
    $this->edit5->text=$array['response']['items'][0]['thumb_photo'];
    $this->editAlt->text=(int)$array['response']['items'][0]['price']['text'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Для одного товара вы записываете его данные в инпуты, а как быть для большего количества товаров. Код ниже проходит в цикле по товарам и перезаписывает инпуты, т.е. там всегда будет последний из списка товар. Скорее всего это поведение вам нужно будет заменить.

```
$h = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/market.get?owner_id=-$group&offset=$offset&count=$count&access_token=$token&v=5.59");
$market_items = json_decode($h,true);
$market_items_length = count($market_items['response']['items']);

for($i = 0; $i < $market_items_length; $i++) {
    $this->edit->text = $market_items['response']['items'][$i]['title'];
    $this->textArea->text = $market_items['response']['items'][$i]['description'];
    $this->edit6->text = $market_items['response']['items'][$i]['price']['currency']['name'];
    $this->edit3->text = $market_items['response']['items'][$i]['category']['name'];
    $this->edit5->text = $market_items['response']['items'][$i]['thumb_photo'];
    $this->editAlt->text = (int) $market_items['response']['items'][$i]['price']['text'];
}
```